# Select 1st item in Autofilter List

Tags: excel, vba

Using VBA how do I code to select the first item in the autofilter list?

Currently I have the below

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Y$840").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    "October"
```

But I want to change the "October" to the 1st item in the dropdown list.

Regards

Jim

Comment: That drop down is just a "Sorted" list of the range. take the range, sort it and use the first cell.

Comment: Is there no quicker way?

Comment: what about `Criteria1:=Range("F2").Value` ?

Comment: but F2 may not be in the filtered list...

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
Option Explicit


Sub calculate()

Dim rn As Range, sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet


SheetCreate
CopyRange



Set sh = Sheet1 ' the sheet where the data you want to filter are.
Set sh1 = Sheets("help to sort")



With sh

Set rn = sh1.Range("A:A")

If .AutoFilterMode = True Then .AutoFilterMode = False

.Range("$A$1:$Y$840").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        rn.Item(2)

End With

End Sub


Sub SheetCreate()

Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet

For Each sh1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If sh1.Name = "help to sort" Then Exit Sub

Next

Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

sh.Name = "help to sort"

End Sub


Sub CopyRange()

Dim rn As Range, rn1 As Range,sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet

Set sh = Sheet1 ' the sheet where the data you want to filter are.
Set sh1 = Sheets("help to sort")

With sh

If sh1.Range("A2") <> "" Then Exit Sub

Set rn = .Range("E:E")
Set rn1 = sh1.Range("A:A")

rn.Copy rn1

rn1.Sort key1:=sh1.Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End With

End Sub
```

if you like you can change the order1 to xldescending

Comment: did you try my last answer?

Comment: Thank you for you input, but I took another approach by cyboashu.

Comment: Nikolaos, thanks for your effort but it filters by the first item in column E for ALL the data range and not the _original_ filtered data.

Comment: you want to filter only the column E?

Comment: I have some data that is already filtered by column A, I want to then filter by column A and by the 1st item in column E. Hope this makes some sense...

Comment: just add in the sub calculate, before ".Range("$A$1:$Y$840").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
        rn.Item(2)" an autofilter rule with field:=1